# Timeout Refilling test account with Lumens

Tags: lumens

anyone experiencing random timeouts within the last 30 minutes to 1 hour when refilling Lumens or doing transaction on the test net ? This is happening even on freshly new created test accounts:

````
data: {
      type: 'https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/timeout',
      title: 'Timeout',
      status: 504,
      detail: 'Your request timed out before completing.  Please try your request again. If you are submitting a transaction make sure you are sending exactly the same transaction (with the same sequence number).'
    }```
````